# qt quick transparent window in windows 7 classic theme

Tags: qt-quick

I create a transparent qml window and everything works well until I change my windows 7 theme to classic, the area I want it to be transparent is black.

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQuick>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
//    QQuickWindow::setDefaultAlphaBuffer(true);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

and My Qml reads

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "#00000000"
    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint//去掉标题栏

    RectangularGlow {
      anchors.fill: background
      glowRadius: 10
      spread: 0
      cornerRadius: 10
      color: "#99999999"
   }

    Rectangle{
        id: background
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        radius: 15
        width: parent.width *2/3
        height: parent.height - 10
        color: "#ffdbeef5"
    }

}
```

anyone has some idea?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIAye.png)

Answer (score 0):

QtQuick transparent window does not work with Win7 classic theme. Transparent windows works only with Aero enabled. There might be some work around or non-QT way of doing this. There were lot of discussion on the bug and it is already reported( https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60130, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52494, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28214)